# Como enviar en codeigniter 4 un correo a una dirección por defecto a través de un formulario

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

He estado viendo la documentacion y he encontrado esto:

```
   $email = \Config\Services::email();

$email->setFrom('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$email->setTo('someone@example.com');
$email->setCC('another@another-example.com');
$email->setBCC('them@their-example.com');

$email->setSubject('Email Test');
$email->setMessage('Testing the email class.');

$email->send();
```

He buscado bastante información en google alr especto pero solo veo tutoriales sobre como hacer un envio de emails via smtp con un dominio de correo, esto no es lo que estoy buscando ya que no dispongo de ello, dispongo de un correo creadod e un cliente en una plataforma y este requiere que se le envien todos los datos de ese formulario al mail que tiene el.

Como hago para que desde un formulario envie la información al correo?

Tengo este formulario:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="InputForName" value="<?= set_value('user_name') ?>" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="InputForEmail" value="<?= set_value('user_email') ?>" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttonHolder">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info text-center">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

y he probado en mi controlador que antiguamente ya guardaba en la base de datos todo lo que se introducia en el formulario a colocar este código del mail, pero no funciona siempre salta a la opción else, por lo tanto imagino que algo debe de ir mal o tal vez esta no es la forma adecuada.

```
public function save()
    {
        //include helper form
        helper(['form']);
        //set rules validation form
        $rules = [
            'name'          => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]',
            'email'         => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[100]|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]'
        ];

        if ($this->validate($rules)) {
            $model = new UserModel();
            $data = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email')
            ];

            $email = \Config\Services::email();

            $email->setFrom($data['user_email'], $data['user_name']);
            $email->setTo('clientemail@email.com');
            /*$email->setCC('another@another-example.com');
            $email->setBCC('them@their-example.com');*/

            $email->setSubject('lorem ipsum '.$data['user_name'].' lorem ipsum');
            $email->setMessage($data['user_name'].' lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum'.$data['user_email']);

            $email->send();

            $model->save($data);
            //return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
            return redirect()->to('/{locale}/gracias');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
        }
    }
```

Tengo que añadir que no tengo configurado email.php porque no lo veo necesario, ya que no dispongo de correo y siempre se manda a un correo fijo, todo lo que se recoge.

He probado otra opción, ya que en php si sabia realizarlo, pero no me ha funcionado o no se como redireccionarlo para que funcione, tal vez con esta opción si logro hacerlo funcionar, he creado una vista llamada enviar.php

```
<?php 
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $asunto = 'Formulario Rellenado';
    $mensaje = "Nombre: ".$nombre."<br> Email: $email<br> Mensaje:".$_POST['mensaje'];


    if(mail('tuEmail', $asunto, $mensaje)){
        echo "Correo enviado";
    }
 ?>
```

Esta vista se encargaría del funcionamiento del envio, recoge los datos del formulario y los manda a un mail.

y aquí estaría el formulario de contacto:

```
<form method='POST' action='/enviar.php'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='nombre' id="nombre" placeholder="nombre...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name='email' id="email" placeholder="email...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name='mensaje' id="mensaje" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" required> Acepto la política de privacidad.
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

He creado una opcion en el controlador que redirija hacia esta página, pero que devuelva a contacto:

```
public function enviar()
{
    $locale = $this->request->getLocale();
    return view('contacto', $this->viewData);
}
```

y la ruta sería:

```
$routes->post('{locale}/enviar', 'Home::enviar');
```

he puesto post ya que se recoge en el formulario y se enviaria aquí. pero esto que en php me resulta tan sencillo no se realizarlo en codeigniter.

Alguien me sabría explicar como se puede realizar lo que intento hacer? gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre salta la opción else, seguramente el problema está en las reglas de validación, no en el envío del correo electrónico (no llega a ejecutar esa parte del código, que por otro lado parece correcto).

Tiene toda la pinta de que el problema puede estar en **is_unique[users.user_email]** del campo email. Esta regla comprueba que que el valor del correo electrónico indicado en el formulario no existe en la columna *user_email* de la tabla *users*. Si, por ejemplo, envío los datos y mi correo es 'nombre@dominio.com' y 'nombre@dominio.com' ya está en esa tabla, va a devolver false y saltará al else. Revisa que realmente necesites hacer dicha verificación.

Trata de simplificar las reglas de validación y vete añadiéndolas una a una para comprobar dónde puede estar la que falla, aunque como digo lo más probable es que sea la de *is_unique* la que esté dando el problema. También simplificaría las reglas del campo email, porque *min_length* y *max_length* son de poca utilidad teniendo en cuenta que con *valid_email* ya puedes discernir si el correo tiene el formato correcto:

```
$rules = [
    'name'  => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]',
    'email' => 'required|valid_email'
];
```

Por cierto, si no vas a enviar ningún archivo adjunto desde el formulario, puedes prescindir de *enctype="multipart/form-data"* en la etiqueta *form*.

**Amplicación de la respuesta**

Incluir el envío directamente en una vista no es la mejor solución, ya que debería estar en el controlador. El código original donde enviabas el correo a través de la librería de CodeIgniter está bien, pero si quieres probar con el método mail(), puedes hacerlo directamente en el controlador de CodeIgniter:

```
public function save()
{
    //include helper form
    helper(['form']);
    
    //set rules validation form
    $rules = [
        'name'  => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]',
        'email' => 'required|valid_email'
    ];

    if ($this->validate($rules)) {
        $model = new UserModel();
        $data = [
            'user_name'  => $this->request->getVar('name'),
            'user_email' => $this->request->getVar('email')
        ];

        // Valores de envío para el método mail()...
        $to      = 'clientemail@email.com';
        $subject = 'lorem ipsum ' . $data['user_name'] . ' lorem ipsum';
        $message = $data['user_name'] . ' lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum' . $data['user_email'];
        
        // Si el envío no se ha podido realizar, detiene el código y muestra error...
        if ( ! mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
            die('El mensaje no se ha enviado');
        }

        $model->save($data);

        return redirect()->to('/{locale}/gracias');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
    }
}
```

Aún así, si como parece tampoco funciona con mail(), tiene pinta que el problema con el envío está más bien en la configuración del servidor.

Comment: He probado esto que me has dicho  y efectivamente ahora si entra en la sección y ejecuta la página de gracias, pero no realiza el envio del mail, no tengo configurado email.php, ya que no requiero enviar emails con un correo, sino enviar emails a un correo concreto siempre el mismo con el correo y nombre del cliente. Esto con php se que se puede hacer sin problema y no requiero de dominio de correo, pero no logro hacerlo en codeigniter.

Comment: Los errores de envío con CodeIgniter son bastante comunes, sobretodo en entornos de pruebas o servidores locales. Si sustituyes la línea $email->send() por $email->send(false) y añades debajo print_r($email->printDebugger()), te mostrará más información del envío.

Comment: Estoy probando el envio en la web real, de todas formas voy a probar eso que me dices a ver y te comento

Comment: nada no me funciona esto que me has pasado no sale ningun print ni nada. directamente se va a la página de gracias, así que la he desactivado y tampoco logro ver nada.

Comment: Perdón, se me olvidó comentar que tendrías que comentar temporalmente la línea donde redireccionas a la página de agradecimiento para evitar que lo haga y así poder ver el contenido del print_r del debugger.

Comment: si si lo hice pero nada no funcionó, he añadido mas información a la pregunta inicial sobre otra cosa que he probado.

Comment: Hay varios problemas con lo nuevo que has probado, no creo que sea una buena solución. Ten en cuenta que no estás incorporando el método de envío a la vista, cuando debería estar en el controlador. Edito mi respuesta para indicarte cómo podrías incorporar el método mail() a tu controlador.

Comment: Vale gracias! estoy super perdida y no lo logro hacer funcionar de ninguna forma no se si realmente me dejaba alguna cosa.

Comment: Ya he añadido una ampliación a la respuesta incluyendo cómo podrías usar mail() dentro del controlador en lugar de la librería de CodeIgniter. Esa parte del código original ya estaba bien, creo que el problema puede estar en la configuración del servidor.

Comment: Si sigue sin funcionar, la librería Email de CodeIgniter puede enviar correos, además de utilizando mail, por sendmail o SMTP. Puedes probar a hacerlo cambiando la configuración del archivo 'app/config/Email.php'. Tienes un ejemplo de cómo configurar un envío por SMTP aquí: https://www.positronx.io/codeigniter-send-email-with-smtp-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: Muchisimas gracias justo era lo que necesitaba!! me has ayudado muchisimo, ya no sabia donde buscar la verdad y no entendía nada he iniciado una recompansa para darte 50 puntos por tu ayuda :) estoy super agradecida!

Comment: No te preocupes por los puntos, no hacen falta. ¡Me alegro de que ya funcione!

Comment: Me ayudaste de una forma espectacular, pregunte también en el foro en inglés y nadie supo ayudarme, gracias enserio te lo merecias.